# Vue how to call filter from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I be able to call filter of parent using single file component. Below are my code.

**app.js**

```
import computed from '../vue/mixins/computed.js';
import filters from '../vue/mixins/filters.js';
import methods from '../vue/mixins/methods.js';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mixins:[
        computed,
        filters,
        methods
    ],
    mounted: function() {

    }
});
```

**home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="home-content">
        <h3>{{home | uppercase}}</h3>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                home: 'home'
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.$parent.$options.methods.makeConsole();
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's giving me this warning in console "Failed to resolve filter: uppercase"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266157/how-to-apply-a-filter-within-a-vuejs-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point. Just include your mixin in the child as well. A component should ideally be autonomous, and not aware of where it is in the hierarchy of components (at least not the ones above or on the same level.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. You could have all main functions inside the parent if two or more child component(s) could call them.

Answer (score 5):

- You should just make the filter global available before starting the root instance with

  ```
  Vue.filter('uppercase', uppercase);
  ```

  Where uppercase can be a simple function like

  ```
  function uppercase(str)
    return str.uppercase();
  }
  ```

  That would be the most simple and reliable way to use the filter on all vue components;
- If you import your filters to your parent via mixins why don't you use that mixin in the child?
- Please do not use the `this.$parent`-method as it makes your child component statical dependend of that parent.

  - To use the `$parent` approach you may need to declare the filter function from the parent as a filter in the child:

    filters:{
      uppercase: this.$parent.$options.filters.uppercase
    }